# PHP - reading folder names without knowing them beforehand

Tags: php, file, directory

This question stems from my lack of knowledge in php, but it would be really helpful if it is possible to in a folder directory such as this one:

```
-Folder
  -SubFolder
     -SubSubFolder
     -SubSubFolder
  -SubFolder
      -SubSubFolder
  ...
```

Note: I know the name of the 'Folder' folder in my directory. I know in php I can do something like:

```
 file_exists($filename) ($filename being path)
```

To do:

- Loop through all the 'Subfolders' in my Folder directory
- Loop through all the SubSubFolders for each Subfolder
- Generate a string coming from the name of the SubSubFolder in combination with its parent SubFolder
- Put this string in a array and at the end return an array of all the 'SubSubFolders' in my directory.

Is something like this possible in PHP? The issue I cant seem to figure out is how to actually check something like this without knowing the path beforehand. When you loop through a directory can you get information about the file?

Thanks

Comment: See opendir('.').  I seems to open the current directory.  See for more functions and examples that may help you:http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: SPL Directory Iterator is viable too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible, there are tons of different ways to do this, I would first take a look at `scandir`.

```
$files_and_folders = scandir('/home/ryankemp/public_html/');
```

This creates an array, in my case with `print_r`, returns:

```
Array ( [0] => - [1] => .htaccess [2] => index.html )
```

`-` being the only folder in the directory and all the files in the directory are listed as well (`.htaccess` and `index.html`). You can add your logic from the array returned, or look up the other PHP folder and file functions `opendir`, `readdir`, `scandir`, `glob` etc...